# pandas 0.20: How do I do a custom sort of the columns with multi-level indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-level

New to pandas. Using pandas 0.20, so no CategoricalDtype. I want to do a custom sort of the columns after merging a few df with concat. The merged df will have multi-level indexed columns.

Using Categorical, it doesn't work for custom sort.

```
dfs=[table2, table3,table4]
L_list=['A', 'B', 'C']     
test=pd.Categorical(L_list, categories=['B', 'C','A'], ordered=True)

merged_df = pd.concat(

    dfs, axis=1,

    keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([

        test,       # Top Level Keys

        ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat1']  # Second Level Keys

    ], names=['Importance', 'Category'])

)

output=merged_df.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0])
```

**Current State**

```
**Merged_df**

Importance| A         |  B   | C       |
Category | Cat1       | Cat2 | Cat1    |
         |Total Assets| AUMs | Revenue |
Firm 1   | 100        | 300  | 300     |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 | 200     |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  | 400     |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  | 350     |
```

**Desired State**

```
**Merged_df**

Importance|  B   | C       | A            |
Category  | Cat2 | Cat1    | Cat1         |
         |AUMs | Revenue | Total Assets |
Firm 1   | 300  | 300     | 100          |  
Firm 2   | 3400 | 200     | 200          |  
Firm 3   |  800  | 400     | 300          |  
Firm 4   |  800  | 350     | NaN          |
```

Comment: if you do `merged_df[['B', 'C','A']]` it works in 0.20? I assume yes. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Ben.T: Thanks! merged_df[['B', 'C','A']] works! But what if I want a custom sort for level 1 indexes too? merged_df[['Cat1', 'Cat2']] doesn't work

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you're using v 0.20? That's from back in 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure of all possibilities with 0.20, but an idea is to convert the multiindex column to a frame, change each level to categorical data (like you did with test in your question), then sort_values the dataframe, keep the index that is columns sorted as you wanted to rearange merged_df columns. see with this example:

```
# simple example
dfs=[
    pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1]}, index=[0,1]), 
    pd.DataFrame({'b':[0,1]}, index=[0,1]), 
    pd.DataFrame({'c':[0,1]}, index=[0,1]),
]

L_list=['A', 'B', 'B'] # changed C to have 2 B with 2 Cat  

merged_df = pd.concat(
    dfs, axis=1,
    keys=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        test,       # Top Level Keys
        ['Cat1', 'Cat1', 'Cat2']  # Second Level Keys
    ], names=['Importance', 'Category'])
)
print(merged_df)
#      A    B     
#   Cat1 Cat1 Cat2
#      a    b    c
# 0    0    0    0
# 1    1    1    1
```

so you can do

```
# create dataframes of columns names
col_df = merged_df.columns.to_frame()

# change to catagorical each level you want
col_df[0] = pd.Categorical(col_df[0], categories=['B', 'C','A'], ordered=True)
col_df[1] = pd.Categorical(col_df[1], categories=['Cat2', 'Cat1'], ordered=True)

# sort values and get the index
print(col_df.sort_values(by=col_df.columns.tolist()).index)
# MultiIndex([('B', 'Cat2', 'c'), # B is before A and Cat2 before Cat1
#             ('B', 'Cat1', 'b'),
#             ('A', 'Cat1', 'a')],
#            )
output = merged_df[col_df.sort_values(by=col_df.columns.tolist()).index]
print(output)  
#      B         A
#   Cat2 Cat1 Cat1
#      c    b    a
# 0    0    0    0
# 1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can u explain how it works? Why would the boolean mask (col_df.sort_values(by=col_df.columns.tolist()).index) work in sorting merged_df?

Comment: I have some situations where this method doesn't work well. Just want to understand more so I can make the tweaks. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. It didn't work due to some differences in the name of the columns and the categories in pd.Categorical. But I would still like to understand how it works.

Comment: Pls assist. Thanks!

Comment: @Peter what I can say is that using `Categorical`, you can overwrite the order of sorting (that is by default alphanumerical order). in `col_df`, by replacing the columns with `Categorical`, you'll be able to order as you define in `categories` parameter. Also, `col_df` index is actually the columns from `merge_df`, so, by sorting `col_df` on the all the columns with `.sort_values(by=col_df.columns.tolist())`  with your custom order, then the index of `col_df` is order as you define in the categories, then getting the `index` will get the ordered columns in `merged_df`, hope it helps